# Running a process under systemd init for containerization?

Tags: systemd, docker, init, container, podman

Docker provides for the ability to run a command when the container starts. This is specified with [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) in the Dockerfile.

However, if I want my container to start with systemd I have to use,

```
CMD ["/usr/sbin/init"]
```

Only then is init in ps1. If this is required, is `CMD` of any use? Is there anyway to start systemd, **and have it start another process too** from the command line, or what `podman run` specifies?

There are multiple different dumb init processes for containerization like, [`catatonit`](https://github.com/openSUSE/catatonit), [`dumb-init`](https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init), and [`tini`](https://github.com/krallin/tini) but they're all "dumb". I want a real systemd init with the ability to specify the process after the default.target is hit.

Answer (score 0):

You’re using `CMD` to configure your container to start systemd, so it seems to me it is “useful”.

To start another command in your container, either:

- on the command line, use `docker exec`;
- in the container definition, use a systemd service.